# TypedDataSet: Why does .NET Framework accepts string in int datatable column?

Tags: c#

Here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rupadhyaya/TypedDataSets12032005021013AM/TypedDataSets.aspx it says:
"we can specify the Data type when we create a DataColumn for a DataTable. This is to enforce the runtime Type-safety for the column so that only data of specified data type can be stored in the column. In the same way, in most of the cases we prefer to make a DataSet itself as Type-safe so as to protect it from runtime mismatch. Hence Typed DataSets generate classes that expose each object the in the DataSet in Type-safe manner. These classes inherits directly from DataSet class."

But this works whereas it shouldn't as I store id.ToString() and not id in typeof(int) id column ?

```
using System;
using System.Data;

public class MyClass {

    public static void Main() {

        DataTable custTable = new DataTable("Customers");
        // add columns
        custTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        custTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
        custTable.Columns.Add("address", typeof(string));

        // set PrimaryKey
        custTable.Columns[ "id" ].Unique = true;
        custTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { custTable.Columns["id"] };

        // add ten rows
        for(int id=1; id<=10; id++)
        {
            custTable.Rows.Add(
                new object[] { id.ToString(), string.Format(
                "customer{0}", id.ToString()), string.Format("address{0}", id.ToString()) });
        }

        custTable.AcceptChanges();

        foreach (DataRow row in custTable.Rows) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",row["id"],row["name"]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

Comment: this is one of the big advantages when you use LINQ (esp. Linq-to-SQL): the compiler can do type-checking, other than in this case here.....

Comment: I cannot use LINQ-to-SQL as I use Oracle and .NET 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the rest of the article that you linked to, not just the first sentence.  The code you posted creates an *untyped* DataSet.  A *typed* DataSet is created with the DataSet Designer, and does, in fact, enforce type-safety at compile time.  In a typed DataSet, you'd have a `CustomersRow` class that exposed an int `id` property and string `name` and `address` properties, and you'd get a compile-time error if you tried to set `id` to a string value.

As it happens, the ADO classes convert values into the appropriate data types at runtime if they can.  So even though your code sets `id` to a string, the data actually stored in the `DataRow` is an int - try to set `id` to "a" and you'll get a run-time error.  This works the other way around, too; if you set `customer` to the integer 11, you'll find it actually contains the string "11".

Comment: Hi thanks, I have tested with "a", it generates an error, that's what I wanted, I just need at runtime, I don't care at design time.

Answer (score 3):

your example is not an area of responsibility  of compiler. you creating  array of objects so nothing wrong here

Maybe you asking why this string value accepted as int value by database?. May be your library recognized id.ToString as a proper integer or may be it was done by database engine. Because at SQL level all converted to just text

Comment: OK I reformulate, not the C# compiler but ADO.NET responsability then ?

Comment: definitely ASP.NET do in in an automatic way.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler has no notion of what the DataTable class should and should not accept.

The Add method of the rows collection takes a bunch of Object references, so it's valid to send any data types you want into it. It tries to convert the data at runtime, and if you send in some data that can't be converted you get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable class is like a look up table of string column name & object value, the type parameter you pass is not used by the compiler.